# CSS greyscale and brightness at same time

Tags: css, css-filters

I wanted to change image to grayscale(0.9) and brightness (120%) at the same time. How can I do that?

```
    img{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.9);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2);
    }
```

How?

Comment: `-webkit-filter: grayscale(0.9) brightness(1.2);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
img {
  filter: grayscale(0.9) brightness(1.2);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://beerhold.it/400/300">
```